# Bash for loop and glob expansion

Tags: bash

Consider the following bash code:

```
 for f in /tmp/*.dat; do echo ${f}; done
```

when I run this and there is no `*.dat` file in `/tmp` the output is:

```
/tmp/*.dat
```

which is clearly not what I want. However, when there is such a file, it will print out the correct one

```
/tmp/foo.dat
```

How can I force the for loop to return 'nothing' when there is no such file in the directory. The `find`-command is not an option, sorry for that :/ I would like to have also a solution without testing, if `*.dat` is a file or not. Any solutions so far?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
shopt -s nullglob
...
```

[From Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-shopt)

> nullglob
>
> If set, Bash allows filename patterns which match no files to expand
>   to a null string, rather than themselves.

Comment: Interesting reading: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#nullglob